# Scala functional composition

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get a function currying working correctly. What I have is the following:

```
    def method(x: ByteArrayInputStream)
              (y: ByteArrayOutputStream)
              (z: GZIPOutputStream)
              (func: (ByteArrayInputStream, GZIPOutputStream) => Unit) = {

    .....
    .....

    }
```

Now when I call it, I call it like this:

```
    method(new ByteArrayInputStream("".getBytes("UTF-8"))) 
          (new ByteArrayOutputStream()) 
          (new GZIPOutputStream(_)) 
          (myFunc(_, _))
```

My understanding is that in the third parameter i.e., to the GZIPOutputStream, when I say _, it will pick the value from the second parameter. But it complains saying that

```
Type mismatch, expected: GZIPOutputstream, actual: (OutputStream) => GZIPOutputStream
```

Any hints?

Comment: You have defined one method with four parameter lists each taking a single parameter. You have not created a curried `Function`. Where you're using underscores in invoking this method you're actually using partial application (of the `GZIPOutputStream` constructor and of `myFunc`, whatever that is). I'm not sure what you're accustomed to, but Scala isn't Haskell and curried functions, which can be created, are not so typically used. At least not outside the FP purist community who often use ScalaZ.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I don't think the _ is a partially applied function in this example... it expands to actual: (OutputStream) => GZIPOutputStream... in which none of the arguments are partially applied

Comment: @AndrewCassidy: I cannot think of a definition of `myFunc` for which those underscores would *not* be for partial application. Can you suggest one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at

```
(new GZIPOutputStream(_))
```

As your error says, your method wants a a `GZIPOutputstream`, but you are passing it a function from `OutputStream` to `GZIPOutputStream`

The underscore is a little confusing at first, but it is the way to tell scala that you are intentionally not passing an argument to `GZIPOutputStream` so that it won't complain about missing arguments. In other words, you are passing the function itself instead of the result of the function.

How to fix it depends on what you're actually trying to do. If you actually want to pass a `GZIPOutputStream`, you'll  need to replace that `_` with an `OutputStream`.

If your intent is to have `method` create a `GZIPOutputStream` given a factory function like the one you are passing, you'd want to change the declared type for `z`. Eg,

```
(z: (OutputStream) => GZIPOutputStream)
```

and then in the method body you could say something like `z(y)` to get a `GZIPOutputStream`. (Or replace `y` with some other output stream.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure how to do this... but here is one solution that mimics what you are looking for

```
def add(j: Int)(i: Option[Int] = None): Int = j + i.getOrElse(j)
add(5)()
```

The add(5)() returns 10 and uses the j value

Comment: also @user3102968 this myFunc(_, _) is definitely not going to work.  Applying that function will return unit while you method expects a function

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to skin that a bit and here is what I have been to:

```
val bytePayload = method(new ByteArrayInputStream(s.getBytes("UTF-8")))(new ByteArrayOutputStream())(writeBytes(_,_))

  def method(bin: ByteArrayInputStream)
            (bos: ByteArrayOutputStream)
            (func: (ByteArrayInputStream, GZIPOutputStream) => Unit): Either[String, Array[Byte]] = {
    val gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bos)

    try {
      func(bin, gzip)
      gzip.finish
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Left(e.getMessage)
    } finally {
      bin.close()
      bos.close()
      gzip.close()
    }
    Right(bos.toByteArray)
  }
```

Though I still handle Exceptions, I'm to some extent convinced that I don't throw them around.